# Do I need Entity Framework Referenced In My UI even if access is limited to my data access layer?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, n-layer

I have an n-layered application with data base activity performed in my data access layer. I have an application layer which asks my data access layer to perform tasks from the repositories in the data access layer. My user interface, which for now is a simple console app to test results, asks my application layer to get things like a list of data which in turn the application layer gets from the repository and it all gets back to the console app.

If I don't add the entity framework as a reference in my console app, I get the following error:

> The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.

Why am I getting this error when the console app makes no data access calls or entity framework operations? All that is done in my data access layer which does have Entity Framework referenced.

Update:
Below is my console interface:

```
class MyServices
{
    IProductRequestServices _ProductRequestServices;
    public MyServices(IProductRequestServices _ProductRequestServices)
    {
        this._ProductRequestServices = _ProductRequestServices;
    }
    public void ProductList()
    {
        List<ProductRequestDetailDto> aList = _ProductRequestServices.GetProductRequestExtendedDetailAll();
        foreach (ProductRequestDetailDto prodReq in aList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Product Req ID: {0} - Product Name: {1}",
                prodReq.productRequestId.ToString(), prodReq.productName);
        }
    }
    public void ClientList()
    {
        List<ProductRequestDetailDto> aList = _ProductRequestServices.GetProductRequestExtendedDetailAll();
        foreach (ProductRequestDetailDto prodReq in aList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Product Req ID: {0} - Product Name: {1}",
                prodReq.productRequestId.ToString(), prodReq.firstName + " " + prodReq.lastName);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
     ProductRequestServices _ProductRequestServices = new ProductRequestServices();

     MyServices MyServices = new MyServices(_ProductRequestServices);

        MyServices.ProductList();
        System.Console.WriteLine("============================");
        MyServices.ClientList();
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Below is the App.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MDISContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelEntities.csdl|res://*/ModelEntities.ssdl|res://*/ModelEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN-2012-SRVR-3;initial catalog=MDIS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

If I just remove the entityFramework  sections and database strings I get the following error:

{"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: \r\nModelEntities.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."}

Then if I remove the configuration section which does an entityframework registstration I get the same error.

All these errors go away if I add EntityFramework to the consoled project of my solution which also adds these entries into the app.config

Comment: The UI layer shouldn't know about the ORM that is used in the data layer. It should just program against interfaces that promise to return some type of entity.

Comment: @LeonCullens ok I got that. And I'm using dependency injection to use the application layer services so why am I getting the above error if I don't have a reference to Entity Framework? There is no mention of any of its functions in my console app?

Comment: I bet your app.config has a reference to the above assembles (e.g. DbFactory, etc.) - remove these and try again.

Comment: @MarkLopez I have provided more information to the problem and I have tried removing EntityFramework references.

Comment: Normally, the layer that initializes DI needs references to everything or at least needs to know about everything. This layer should also be the top layer.

EF will pull the connection strings from the config file of the appdomain. It also uses the DB Factories that are initialized from the the same config file (therefore that appdomain needs a reference to the EF driver in use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository layer is going to look for the EF config in the configuration file loaded for the running app domain. So yes, your console app needs the configuration and that requires EF references. If your repositories were in an external service or another process then you would  not need EF references.

Comment: Your response makes more sense to me.  Each of my layers is in a separate project (i.e. UI, App Services, Domain, Infrastructure-Data Access).  All layers below the UI are created as separate assemblies (DLLs), but only the UI, in this case a console app, outputs a .EXE which means the console Is the running app

Answer (score 0):

only data/ repository layer should know the Db related dlls/ logics, but I faced same issue with entity framework. 
MSBuild was not copying this EF SQL dll in bin/debug folder. I had to include this dll in my UI project.

Reason, if I remember it correctly, is because of some intelligent stuff MSBuild was trying to do, which is: If its not able to find a reference in some kind of dependency tree, it will not include it in output or bin/debug folder. (i don't remember the source of this)